# html tag or class to specific words with Javascript or Jquery, without targeting Alts and Titles of the pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, tags

some time ago I asked for help to automatically change certains repetitive names of my website and make them italic. With your help I managed to do what I wanted by using this script:

```
function change() {
    var words = new Array("Nymphaea", "Nelumbo", "Iris", "Hemerocallis", "Hibiscus");
    var html = document.body.innerHTML;
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var reg = new RegExp(words[i], 'g');
        var html = html.replace(reg, "<i>"+words[i]+"</i>");
    }
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
change();
```

Unfortunately I just realized I still have a problem since all the pictures show a title with a  tag. For example, if the html is:

```
<a href="......../nymphaea-alba-var-rubra.jpg" title="&lt;i&gt;Nymphaea&lt;/i&gt; alba var. rubra"><img src="/wp-uploads/gallery/nursery/nymphaea-alba-var-rubra.th.jpg" alt="&lt;i&gt;Nymphaea...&lt;/i&gt; alba var. rubra" /> </a>
```

the picture shows a title like < i > Nymphaea < /i > alba var. rubra. Can anyone help me refine the code in order for Titles and Alts not to be targeted? I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Enrico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a regex on the amended HTML to remove any italic tags in title and alt attributes, like so:

```
function change() {
    var words = new Array("Nymphaea", "Nelumbo", "Iris", "Hemerocallis", "Hibiscus");
    var html = document.body.innerHTML;
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        var reg = new RegExp(words[i], 'g');
        var html = html.replace(reg, "<i>"+words[i]+"</i>");
    }
    html = html.replace(/([title|alt]=".*?)<i>(.*?)<\/i>(.*?")/gm, '$1$2$3');
    document.body.innerHTML = html;
}
change();
```

Comment: Seems I can't cause I don't have 15 reputations, I'm sorry Matt :(